# Cheese won't start

Tags: 11.10, webcam, cheese

I can't start Cheese Webcam Booth. It starts loading and there is a brief moment when the window shows up but then it disappears, like it shuts itself down and it's not in system monitor.

My webcam works perfectly in Skype video call. I installed and run Camorama and it gave me an error: Could not connect to video device (/dev/video0) Please check connection

When I run the `lsusb` I get this line for my webcam:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b210 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

And for my graphic card, running `lspci`:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

It's not a pressing matter, but it bugs my nerves, if it works on Skype, why does Cheese and other programs refuse to run. As I said, it's not a big deal but any help would be appreciated.

Running Cheese in terminal:

```
(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkHBox to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkHBox to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:11454): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'cheese' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 932 error_code 9 request_code 137 minor_code 9)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Comment: You should try running `cheese` from a terminal and edit your question to include any errors it pushes out.

Comment: Done. It all looks like ancient Egyptian to me, it's so hard to learn Linux when you've been on Windows whole life...

Comment: Have you [reported a bug](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/18612) for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same errors, found bug reports everywhere. Did not feel like debugging software to take a snapshot.

I installed `guvcview` instead by running:

```
sudo aptitude install guvcview
```

Running `guvcview` worked out of the box for my Logitech, Inc. Webcam C200.